# what is missing in a container image that prevents it connecting its process directly to the NIC

Tags: c

In a process running as a container you have to connect the IP stack to the outside world, for example by using a veth device. But you don’t have to do this with a normal process i.e. a process not running in a container but in the actual linux o.s.
So say if I write a c program that has a socket call with SOCK_DGRAM param and a call to the bind function. When I run this program on a Linux o.s. the program can send UDP packets over the NIC. But if I run this program as a container, the program will not work unless the container image is connected to an external device (by for example running ip command with using a veth).
The container has a cut down version of linux. What functionality is missing in this cut-down linux image that prevents it from connecting to the NIC?

Comment: It's probably just how you're running your containers. Is this Docker? Are the container networks set to host, bridge, something else?

Comment: In terms of how this is implemented, I'd guess the contained images talk to virtual devices provided by the container host and it's up to the container host which messages get passed on to the real NIC or not.